# How to use Atom's LaTeX package?

Tags: latex, atom

I'm very newbie, please don't annoy for my question.

I've installed LaTeX using `apt-get install texlive-full` but really don't know where it has been installed. As from Atom's LaTeX package needs TeX distribution's bin directory, so I tried to find it, but I could only find `/etc/texmf/` and `/usr/local/share/texmf` which not seem to be what I want.

So, I would like to ask if what should I do to be able to use LaTeX package in Atom and should I create a PATH for Texlive?

Sorry for weird question and thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to [`latex`](https://atom.io/packages/latex) package or [`language-latex`](https://atom.io/packages/language-latex) or [`latextools`](https://atom.io/packages/latextools)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the issue is not one of setting your TeX distribution's binary directory (which, unless you have installed it to a non-standard location, should be `/usr/bin` anyway). Rather, it is because the Atom LaTeX package requires `latexmk`, which is not part of the texlive distribution.

So the solution appears to be to install the `latexmk` package, either using Software Center or from the terminal using `sudo apt install latexmk`. You should be able to leave the Atom LaTex package's `Tex Path` setting empty.